# In putty UTF-8 character edit is not working?

Tags: putty, utf-8

I am using putty (version .70) and character set type UTF-8 is enabled. Running C program in CentOS machine also an environmental variable `$LANG` is set as en_GB.UTF-8. I am getting the user input(through scanf) as UTF-8 (for example: 中国话不用) to count UTF-8 characters. It is Ok, but I want to change the user input(through scanf) again (For Ex:中国话) from the existing one.If I want to change the user input I need to use "backspace" key twice to delete the single UTF-8 character. Why it is not working in output window?

[image]

You can see the space between the cursor and next character which leads to wrong count. How to solve this issue

Comment: What? Why do you need to delete characters if you want to count characters?

Comment: @seth For ex: I want to get the user input as "中国话不用彁字。". Now I am going to input the above 3 characters only by editing as "中国话" which needs to use backspace key to delete at that time we need to press 2 backspace key to delete single UTF-8 character in putty window.

Comment: Yes but I still don't get what you're trying to do. You're saying you want to count UTF-8 characters. That program apparently takes `stdin` so you type your Chinese characters and all of a sudden you're talking about deleting characters just to close with a question about the output - which you never mentioned up until that point.

Comment: changed the description

Comment: Did you check the documentation and your compiler settings whenever they're setup to correctly handle multibyte characters? UTF-8 can use multiple codepoints to represent a single character. So you might end up in situations where you're deleting single codepoints rather than the complete "character".